# DeploymentRuleSet occupying most of the heap space

Tags: java, heap-memory, jnlp, heap-dump, eclipse-memory-analyzer

We are getting an OOME on our Java Web Start application
When analyzing the heap size in JVisualVM we are seeing a large increase in memory over a short period.
The following memory consumption is more or less the same every time when running the application.

[image: Memory consumption over 10 minutes]

I have imported the heap dump to Eclipse MAT.
I can see that most of the heap is occupied by DeploymentRuleSets
The internal drs map of the DeploymentRuleSet class contains tens of thousands entries all containing the same jar

[image: MAT leak suspect]

I've investigated at least 50 of these HashMap entries. They contain the same data. Screenshot attached - I have taken out some sensitive company data but I really triple checked if the values are the same. I've pasted screenshots of just 2 RuleId objects but you get the picture

[image: Same jar in DRS map entry 1]
[image: Same jar in DRS map entry 2]

Here are my questions/doubts:

1. The obvious one: has anyone encountered anything like this?
2. Looking at the RuleId class, it does not have the "equals" nor "hashcode" method implemented. It is therefor expected that duplicated entries will be inserted to the hashmap since it will compare the objects by reference. 
   However I've analyzed different heap dumps withing our company for other JavaWebStart applications. None of them have the same problem. The drs map contains only a couple hundred entries and there are only unique jars from classpath so exactly how I would expect it to work
   Therefor I doubt that it is a "core java bug" but rather our specific app problem
   Do you have an idea why the same jar would be inserted into the drsMap over and over again?
3. I've attached the remote debugger to our JavaWebStart app. I have imported the core java "deploy.jar" to the classpath and put some breakpoints in some of the DeploymentRuleSet methods. Sadly none of them were hit even though the DeploymentRuleSet increases in memory. Any way to debug core java stuff like this? Would be really helpful to see when and why are those DRS triggered